# Store mousedown locations

Tags: cocoa, mouse, click

My cocoa app calculates the location for every mousedown event. The next time the mouse is clicked, the location is overwritten by the new one. How can I store the locations? Is it possible to create an array with mousedown locations?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can. Since you're dealing with a primitive struct (NSPoint) you'll need to wrap that in an object before you can put it in an NSArray though. NSValue is a ready-made class that allows you to do this, take a look at `[NSValue valueWithPoint:aPoint];`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You could easily do something like this (assume `storedLocations` is an ivar of type `NSMutableArray` and has been properly initialized):

```
NSPoint thePoint = [theEvent locationInWindow];
[storedLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithPoint:thePoint]];
```