# Making an array of NSRect values in mousedown method

Tags: cocoa, mouse, click

My cocoa app calculates the location of every mousedown event. It also checks whether the location is located inside a rectangle using NSPointInRect and while enumerating over an existing mutable array with values of the rectangles. I'm using an if-statement to add the rectangle values in which the mousedown event is located to a new array (selectedRectangles). 
The values are added perfectly to selectedRectangles, only problem is that previous values are overwritten. How can I solve this problem.

PS at the end of the mousedown method I use setNeedsDisplay:YES to update the data (this because selectedRectangles is used in another method).

Comment: Can you post some code that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> add the rectangle values…to a new array

Assuming that you're asking a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726133/). You *don't* want to create a new array each time. You want to make an `NSMutableArray` before any click locations are stored, then use its `addObject:` method to add a new item on each click.